# SAP How to create a view with special conditions and aliases

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to make a view for following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ma~matnr ma~mtart ma~ernam ma~ersda ma~laeda de~maktx as maktx_de fr~maktx as maktx_fr it~maktx as maktx_it
FROM mara as ma
LEFT JOIN MAKT as de ON de~matnr = ma~matnr AND de~spras = 'DE'
LEFT JOIN MAKT as fr ON fr~matnr = ma~matnr AND fr~spras = 'FR'
LEFT JOIN MAKT as it ON it~matnr = ma~matnr AND it~spras = 'IT'
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE g_it_material
```

How can I do that? Where can I choose aliases and special conditions in SE11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the case you've described isn't possible with a dictionary view.

You can certainly define the conditions, but you cannot define field aliases. The only option that would give you a *similar* result is to define an `OR` condition for each language and then process the rows accordingly (it would give you one row per language per material, however). I doubt that would be an acceptable alternative.

**Note** Answer changed - I originally missed the point that you had three joins to `MAKT`.

Comment: If I join a table multiple times I absolutley need aliases not only for display purposes.

Comment: If you use the view in a `SELECT` statement you can use the alias *for* the view, but you cannot define an alias *within* the view. As the view is a self-contained object, it wouldn't make sense anyway...

Comment: So how can I join `MAKTX` once with `SPRAS = 'F'` and once with `SPRAS = 'E'` ? I do not see a solution for that problem without aliases